# Appium testing: Clicking on a textview when clickable=true

Tags: android, appium

Android has a technique where you can turn text into a button.  You set the element to clickable, and then define an onClick() method for it.

On the Appium side, what I'm seeing is that the text for the element ends with an "@" character.  For example from "UI Automator Viewer" :

*(2) TextView: Purchase an item @ [69,1038][1011,1110]*

The '@' is displayed as an arrow symbol on the actual phone, and clicking on the arrow, and only the arrow, will take you to a different dialog (one to make a purchase in this case).  Manually clicking on the text itself does not move the app to the dialog.  Only clicking on the arrow works.

My Python code looks like:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.mycompany.project:id/make_a_purchase_text").click()
```

The click() method does not take me to the correct dialog.  In fact, nothing apparent happens at all.  I am click()ing on a lot of elements that are buttons in order to get to this point, so I know my setup is good.  Is there any support at all in Appium for this sort of control?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is the best way of doing it. To me it seems that selenium WebElement cannot detect the additional properties given to a TextView or a UIAStaticText. So when we assign a click property the base class behind the element cannot do the click event. 
So as a workaround i sent a touch event to the required x,y location

```
driver.executeScript("mobile: tap", new HashMap<String, Double>() {
            {
                put("tapCount", 1d);
                put("touchCount", 1d);
                put("duration", 0.52478515625);
                put("x", 127d);
                put("y", 571d);
            }
        });
```